# Is 吹空调 grammatically correct?

Tags: word-choice

When waiting in line for seats at 南京大牌档 a few days back, a local famous eatery in Nanjing, Jiangsu, I heard a man say "别在外面站着，先进来吹空调".

This is a little weird. 空调 is air conditioner, how can people blow an air conditioner?

Comment: To my knowledge the justification for such expressions as 吹空调, 晒太阳 has long been considered an unsolved problem in Chinese grammar.

Comment: In English, you can “kick your legs”, which doesn’t involve literally kicking your legs., but rather using  your legs for kicking.

Answer (score 4):

别在外面站着，先进来吹空调。
Don't stand outside, once inside you can enjoy the airco.

Of course, you won't go in and blow on the air-conditioner! The air-conditioner is blowing, puffing out cool air!

Look up the ideas of ergative, which is also unaccusative, and unergative.

In 吹空调 you have a kind of Chinese reversed ergative expression which plays havoc with the syntactical notions of subject and object, but is perfectly understandable!

A doorbell can ring, but a doorbell can't ring itself!

I rang the doorbell.
我按了门铃。

Ergative:
The doorbell rang.
门铃响了。

The air-conditioner blew cool air into the room.
空调把冷空气吹进房间里。

吹空调。

Answer (score 1):

I'm a native speaker and it always amazes me how weird some of the grammars are for some everyday phrases.

I think this one is derived from a more traditional phrase, 吹风(since air conditioner is a relatively new thing), which is also weird because it is not to "blow the wind" but rather "get blown by wind".

A lot of weather related expressions have this grammar:

晒太阳 to be bathed by the Sun

淋雨 to be showered by the rain

To be honest I'm not sure why, maybe because the subject is "it"( mother Nature ) so it got hidden?

BTW, 南京大牌档 is the best, I went there a lot during my undergraduate study in Nanjing. Pretty authentic.

Comment: Thanks. I often saw a long queue before that restaurant and wondered what kind of good food it could serve other than duck blood soup? LOL.

Comment: @NanningYouth all the “淮扬菜” is good there: try 清汤狮子头！

Comment: I might have eaten the food you mentioned. Is it the ball of meat that is cooked with some leafy vegetable in soup? Or the fish fried in deep oil?

Comment: @NanningYouth yeah the meet ball in soup.

Answer (score 1):

The full sentence "(你)先進來(吹)**吹空調**吧" is "grammarly correct". Here, **吹空調** is a compound word, or, a phrase, that was made to represent the action "讓風調/冷氣吹一吹" - "let the cool breeze (produced/blown by the AC) to cool you down". Below are a few examples of commonly used compound words/phrases:

- 這風(吹得)好涼爽, "讓我們出去(吹)**吹風**吧" - "Let's go out to enjoy the cool breeze" (produced/brought by the wind).
- 這太陽(曬得)真暖和, "讓我們出去(曬)**曬太陽**吧" - "Let's go out to enjoy the warmth (of the sun).
- 這孩子, 才被雨淋病了, "她怎麽又出去**淋雨**了" - "How could she get wet (by exposing to the rain) again."

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Treat 吹空調 as one single group that has a meaning. Don't break it up.

In English there is "sunbathing," say. So how does the sun bathe, or how can people bathe in the sun?

Answer (score 1):

Is 吹空调 grammatically correct?
Never have correct grammar in Chinese.
汉语是表意的，没有严格的语法。这里的空调相当于冷风的意思，空调这种电器发出的冷风。你这样看就明白了

> 快来吹空调发出的冷风
> 快来，让空调发风吹你

你吹空调，实际上是让空调吹你，或者：你被空调吹。空调不是宾语，不是你发出了一个动作，对空调做了什么。

同样的表达还有

> 他失恋了，晚上一个人在喝闷酒。

有一种牌子的酒，或者状态的酒，叫闷酒吗？没有！这句话实际上是

> 他失恋了，晚上一个人在闷闷地喝酒。

奇特的是，汉语在读的时候，把"闷"和"酒"，连起来一起读，好像有种酒，它是"闷酒"。

请牢牢记住，汉语是表意的，它不讲究严格的语法，特别是口语。

Comment: Good. How about 吹牛皮?

Comment: 吹牛皮就不一样了，牛皮在这里是名词，做吹这个动作的对象。嘴巴能吹牛皮，说明嘴巴厉害，大话多。